# How to troubleshoot lighttpd service not starting up?

Tags: lighttpd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
I have installed lighttpd 8.28.

I have created the folder 
- r-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 16 15:41 httpd

I am pointing my server.document-root to /home/httpd

When I restart the service.

## systemctl restart lighttpd.service

Job for lighttpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status lighttpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I get the following errors on syslog. I am clueless on how can I debug this and what is the real problem here. I have changed the group to 
www-data for my server-document.root.

```
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Lighttpd Daemon...
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox lighttpd[4270]: /usr/sbin/lighttpd: Symbol `FamErrlist' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox lighttpd[4270]: /usr/sbin/lighttpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/lighttpd: undefined symbol: FAMNoExists
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 16 16:28:42 abc-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/1401), especially [this comment](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/1401#issuecomment-475099634), installing `gamin` package should do the trick.